# VAR Display From Javascript Into PHP Display

Tags: php, javascript, get

I am working on a script that requires a user to validate their account (from another website, not my own website). Once the user enters the correct login info, and the login server responds back to my script, it displays the username as

```
" + usernameUrl + "
```

This is the part of the script that defines that value.

```
var usernameUrl = encodeURIComponent(username);
```

I need to put that into a file uploader script which will allow the user to upload a image as .png, and only their own username, no one elses. However I already have that script made, I just need to know how to add that into the script itself. The line which needs to be changed is...

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path."/"<USERNAME>".png");
```

If I need to provide any more information please let me know. :D

More Codes They May or May Not Help This Problem

```
    document.getElementById("spanServerResponse").style.display = "inline";
    var loginName = document.getElementsByName("loginName")[0].value;
    var loginNameUrl = encodeURIComponent(loginName);
    document.getElementById("spanClientLogin").style.display = "none";

    var username = parts[2];  

    //alert("Username: " + username + "\nSessionId: " + sessionId);

    var usernameUrl = encodeURIComponent(username);
    var sessionIdUrl = encodeURIComponent(sessionId);
    var serverHash = "123"; 
    var urlStr = "http://domain.tld/test.jsp?user=" + usernameUrl + "&sessionId=" + sessionIdUrl + "&serverId=" + serverHash;
```

Comment: PHP will never get direct access to Javascript variables. The easiest way to pass values in Javascript to PHP would be to store the results in  cookie. But PHP will only be able to access them on page (re)load.

Answer (score 0):

You can send that varaible via ajax and save it in session. using jquery:

```
$.get('save_var.php', {username: username}, function() {
   // you can now upload a file
});
```

save_var.php should be:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_GET['username'];

?>
```

and you get username from session in your upload script

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path."/" . $_SESSION['username'] . ".png");
```

Maybe you will need to start session before ajax call in the same php file that have javascript code.